# How to create a data frame from the results of an if statement on three data frames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have three data frames d1,d2,d3 with same column names, I want to create a new data frame when if d1 is 1 then d2 value will be assigned if not value of d3 will be assigned.

[image: Data frames]

Comment: Look at np.where

Comment: Could you provide an example of the dataframe layout please?

Comment: I just added the example of the three data frames

Answer (score 1):

Try using `mask`:

```
df3.mask(df1.astype(bool), df2)
```

Or, `where`:

```
df2.where(df1.astpye(bool), df3)
```

MCVE:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'X1':[1]*4, 'X2':[0]+[1]*3, 'X3':[0]+[1]*3}, index = pd.date_range('7/10/2019', periods=4, freq='D'))

            X1  X2  X3
2019-07-10   1   0   0
2019-07-11   1   1   1
2019-07-12   1   1   1
2019-07-13   1   1   1

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100, (4,3)), columns=['X1','X2','X3'], index = pd.date_range('7/10/2019', periods=4, freq='D'))

            X1  X2  X3
2019-07-10  66  92  98
2019-07-11  17  83  57
2019-07-12  86  97  96
2019-07-13  47  73  32

df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10000,1000000, (4,3)), columns=['X1','X2','X3'], index = pd.date_range('7/10/2019', periods=4, freq='D'))

                X1      X2      X3
2019-07-10  699070  524272  206719
2019-07-11  767145  420963  569950
2019-07-12  472077  762036  418160
2019-07-13  664544  879444  869953
```

Output:

```
            X1      X2      X3
2019-07-10  66  524272  206719
2019-07-11  17      83      57
2019-07-12  86      97      96
2019-07-13  47      73      32
```